# Why can't you reflag a question after having retracted a previous flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, retracted-flags

So I came across a question which was off topic and flagged it as such, specifying the *Looking for a tool, tutorial, etc.* reason. I thought about it for a second and figured that the question was still off topic, but the better reason was *Too broad*. I retracted my previous flag, and went to re-flag it for why I felt was the correct reason, but the option is greyed out because I have *retracted my recommended closure flag*.

What's the reason for not allowing users to re-flag a question if they accidentally hit the wrong reason, or feel a better flag may have fit?